# How to draw SVG plots in separate pages of a single file [R]?

Tags: r, svg, plot

How to separate below two plots into different pages ?

command `onefile` is meant for this purpose but somehow the following code draws only last of the two plots.

Any thing missing here ?

```
library(RSVGTipsDevice)

devSVGTips("svgplot9.svg", toolTipMode=1,onefile=TRUE,
title="SVG example plot 9: line and point types")
plot(c(0,20),c(0,5), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y",
main="Example SVG plot with different line and point types")
for (i in 0:16) {
lines(i+(0:4), (1:5), col=max(i,1), pch=i, lty=i, type="b")
text(i, 0.5, lab=as.character(i), cex=2^(abs((i-8)/4)-1))
}


devSVGTips("svgplot9.svg", toolTipMode=1, onefile=TRUE,
title="SVG example plot 10: line and point types")
plot(c(0,20),c(0,5), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y",
main="Example SVG plot with different line and point types")
for (i in 0:16) {
lines(i+(0:4), (1:5), col=max(i,1), pch=i, lty=i, type="b")
text(i, 0.5, lab=as.character(i), cex=2^(abs((i-8)/4)-1))
}

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try with a single call to `devSVGTips` (the second one deletes the file that was being written), either with `onefile=TRUE` (the two plots are overlaid on a single page) or `onefile=FALSE` (the two plots are in the same file, but the XML code describing them is just concatenated: this may not be valid XML and/or may require further processing).

```
# Same code as yours, indented, and with 
# a different title for the second plot to see the difference.
library(RSVGTipsDevice)

devSVGTips(
  "svgplot9.svg", toolTipMode=1,
  onefile=FALSE, # Try with TRUE (overlaid plots) or FALSE (separate plots)
  title="SVG example plot 9: line and point types"
)
plot(
  c(0,20),c(0,5), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y",
  main="Example SVG plot with different line and point types"
)
for (i in 0:16) {
  lines(i+(0:4), (1:5), col=max(i,1), pch=i, lty=i, type="b")
  text(i, 0.5, lab=as.character(i), cex=2^(abs((i-8)/4)-1))
}

#devSVGTips(
#  "svgplot9.svg", toolTipMode=1, onefile=TRUE,
#  title="SVG example plot 10: line and point types"
#)
plot(
  c(0,20),c(0,5), type="n", xlab="x", ylab="y",
  main="Example SVG plot with different line and point types (2)"
)
for (i in 0:16) {
  lines(i+(0:4), (1:5), col=max(i,1), pch=i, lty=i, type="b")
  text(i, 0.5, lab=as.character(i), cex=2^(abs((i-8)/4)-1))
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: Output file generated by modified code gives the following parsing error : - XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: file:/svgplot9.svg
Line Number 439, Column 1:<svg version="1.1"
^

Comment: Removing the lines causing error (438-448) overcomes parsing problems, but only the second plot is drawn !

Comment: What happens is that the two plots are simply put in the same XML file: there will be two <svg> elements, corresponding to the two plots. Since there is no root element, I am not sure this is valid XML -- this is your error message: it just says that there is something after the first plot ends, namely the second plot.

Comment: The correct way to put several pages in the same SVG document is apparently to have a <pageSet> element containing several <page> elements: but that is not what devSVGTips produces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6810/discussion-between-user1029725-and-vincent-zoonekynd)